# How do I identify who initiated mail delivery using my postfix?

Tags: email, postfix

I use debian with postfix as MTA. Recently I noticed a huge mail traffic outgoing of my server. How do I identify the origin (initiator) of the mails? I suppose the "from" field in my logs (mail.log, mail.info, mail.err, mail.warn) is faked. Apart from the target address and target host the log files do not seem to hold useful information to track the source of the mail. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The received headers of the message should contain the information you are looking for.  However, you need to obtain the full headers of the file.  Normally, these are dropped when the message is forwarded.  If you got bounce messages, it is likely they contain the headers.  Find the received header added by your server.  This will contain reliable information on how the email got added to your mail stream.

If the mail arrived over a network configuration (which may have been from localhost), it likely won't include the sender userid.  If you are using a local ident daemon and have enabled queries, you may have details from that.

If you have process accounting enabled, you may be able to identify the sender from those records.